# Prevent XML column from collapsing when tag is empty

Tags: css, xml, xslt, multiple-columns

I have a formatted XML table.  When a tag is empty, the column collapses and the following column prints into that space, messing up the column format.

The XSL file has styles for a series of columns like this:

```
        .drawingrev {
        float: left;
        width: 0.8in;
        text-align:center;
    }
```

The data for each column is displayed:

```
<div class="drawingrev"><xsl:value-of select="Obj_RevisionNumber"/></div>
```

If the value-of is empty, the entry collapses and the next piece of data is written into that space.

I'd appreciate a little help in finding the appropriate settings to reserve the space,

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know that StackOverflow allows you to include HTML and CSS fragments in your question to demonstrate the problem? The whole problem seems more related to HTML and CSS, as these seem to be used as the target format of XSLT. So mock up a little example to show the structure you have and the layout problem it causes. In general these days using flex blox in CSS seems to be preferred to use floats for layouts.

Comment: Martin,  Thanks for your response.  That is literally all the info.  The next column walks and quacks like the first one.  I'll go read up on flex blox and see if I can make that work.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the CSS

```
.drawing-container {
  display: flex; 
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

and change your class to

```
.drawingrev {
    width: 0.8in;
    text-align:center;
}
```

and then make sure that `div`s with `class="drawingrev"` have a parent `div class="drawing-container"`, the CSS flex box layout should just ensure an equal layout of your `div`s, whether they have content or not:

```css
    .drawingrev {
        width: 0.8in;
        text-align:center;
    }
    
    .drawing-container {
        display: flex; 
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
```

```html
      <div class="drawing-container">
         
         <div class="drawingrev">item 1</div>
         
         <div class="drawingrev">item 2</div>
         
         <div class="drawingrev">item 3</div>
         
         <div class="drawingrev">item 4</div>
         
         <div class="drawingrev"></div>
         
         <div class="drawingrev">item 6</div>
         
         <div class="drawingrev">item 7</div>
         
         <div class="drawingrev">item 8</div>
         
         <div class="drawingrev">item 9</div>
         
         <div class="drawingrev"></div>
         
         <div class="drawingrev">item 11</div>
         
         <div class="drawingrev">item 12</div>
         
         <div class="drawingrev">item 13</div>
         
         <div class="drawingrev">item 14</div>
         
         <div class="drawingrev"></div>
         
         <div class="drawingrev">item 16</div>
         
         <div class="drawingrev">item 17</div>
         
         <div class="drawingrev">item 18</div>
         
         <div class="drawingrev">item 19</div>
         
         <div class="drawingrev"></div>
      </div>
```